# Como validar input para evitar espacios vacios provocados por tecla space? vuejs js php

Tags: php, javascript

estoy validando el formulario y tengo para cadena vacia y caracteres especiales, pero si yo al input le doy un al space, este toma valor de cadena vacia y pasa, como puedo evitar eso? estuve probando

```
if (this.name ==== "") {error}
if (this.name == "") {error}
```

como puedo evitar los espacios vacios provocados por el space?

Comment: Podrías utilizar expresiones regulares para verificar si el texto introducido está formado por caracteres  que NO son espacios en blanco y si tiene al menos 2 o 3 caracteres. `var rex = /([^\s]{3,})/g`

Comment: Otra opción es usar `trim` en [`PHP`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.trim.php) o en [`Javascript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/Trim)